# PythonShell.py:27: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_info' was never awaited mpl.use('AGG')

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to convert the following function into asynchronous function to make asynchronous calls to REST endpoint:

```
def get_info(data, url, mini_batch = 1000):
  responses = []

  for first in range(0, len(data), mini_batch):
      data = data[first:first+mini_batch].tolist()

      input_json_data = json.dumps(data)

      headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

      resp = requests.post(url, input_json_data, headers=headers)
      responses.append(json.loads(resp.text).get('result'))

  output = numpy.concatenate([numpy.array(i) for i in responses])
  return output
```

I found [these examples](https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/using-asynchronous-for-loops-in-python.html) for Python 3. This is what I tried:

```
import asyncio

asynch def get_info(data, url, mini_batch = 1000):

  await asyncio.sleep(1)

  responses = []

  async for first in range(0, len(data), mini_batch):
      data = data[first:first+mini_batch].tolist()

      input_json_data = json.dumps(data)

      headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

      resp = requests.post(url, input_json_data, headers=headers)
      responses.append(json.loads(resp.text).get('result'))

  output = numpy.concatenate([numpy.array(i) for i in responses])
  return output
```

Then I call this function as follows:

```
output = asyncio.run(get_info(data, url, mini_batch))
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got range
```

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I tried using the suggestion regarding `aiohttp`:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url, headers, input_json_data):
    async with session.post(url, input_json_data, headers) as response:
        return await json.loads(response.text).get('result')


async def get_info(input_data, url):

  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    input_json_data = json.dumps(input_data.tolist())
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    output = await fetch(session, url, headers, input_json_data)

  return output
```

Call:

```
asyncio.run(get_info(data, url))
```

or

```
asyncio.gather(get_info(data, url))
```

Error:

> PythonShell.py:27: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_info' was
>   never awaited   mpl.use('AGG') RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to
>   get the object allocation traceback TypeError: post() takes 2
>   positional arguments but 4 were given

or

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'
```

Comment: In the linked example, `async for` is used to iterate over the results of an async generator. In your code you are iterating over a normal iterator, so you should continue using `for`. Note that you are using `requests`, so your code will block the event loop and isn't compatible with asyncio - you should use aiohttp instead. Also note that both `for` and `async for` are sequential in nature - you should use `asyncio.gather()` or equivalent to achieve concurrent execution.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks. I'm looking at this example: https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/ It's unclear how to pass `header` and how to do a POST request… Could you please put an example?

Comment: That is just the pypi front page of the project, not its actual documentation, which is [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). It covers POST requests in detail [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests); if you get stuck, please post a separate question.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks. Yes, I get stuck as shown in my update. But sorry, why should I post another question?

Comment: Because a stackoverflow question is supposed to cover one issue, not pivot as you make progress with your assignment. The original title of the question was about a specific problem with `__aiter__` to which I responded in a comment; now it is a very general "how to perform async HTTP requests" (which is too broad). Moving the goalpost makes the question basically unanswerable and makes it unappealing to spend time on it. Please have in mind that this site is run by volunteers who like to tackle interesting problems; keeping the question focused will improve its chances of getting answered.

Comment: @user4815162342: Understood. Yes, makes sense. Let me please change a title of this question to make it more focused on the last error. I will not change it anymore. Sorry.